# Docker Mac Beta using insecure Private Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am using Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe on Mac OS X

On my Mac machine I am trying to do docker push to private docker registry running on remote VM. I am unable to get SSL to work and want to use insecure registry following instructions on https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/ How Can I specify DOCKER_OPTS on my Mac so I can push the image to private registry?

Answer (score 3):

In case other people are having the same `Get https://docker.myregistry.io:5000/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` problem, I've posted [a simple solution on my blog](https://codetrips.com/2016/09/13/docker-for-mac-and-insecure-registries/): it all boils down, as @manojlds has pointed out, to whitelisting the server in the `Advanced` preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the response on docker forums - https://forums.docker.com/t/where-do-i-set-docker-opts-for-insecure-registry/14542

```
pinata set daemon '{"storage-driver":"aufs","debug":true,"insecure-registries":["your.insecure.registry.com:5000"]}'
```

Comment: Docker ver 1.12 also added "insecure registries" in advanced preference.

Answer (score 0):

Pinata has been removed from more recent versions. You can setup insecure registries from `Preferences -> Advanced`.

Currently there is no official CLI based way to do the update.